# How to upload file from client pc to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a web application in asp.net c# , I want to upload a file from  client machine to server.I have used to the following code

```
    string path = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentPath"]);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path) + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 string path = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentPath"]);
string strImageName3 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
string strFilePath3 = Server.MapPath(path);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(strFilePath3 + strImageName3);
```

this `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")` for adding `yyyyMMddHHmmssfff` string to the uploaded file name for unique uploaded filename.

Comment: I  used to this command in web config file  <add key="DocumentPath" value="\\10.100.159.36\Uploadfile\\ "  />

Comment: `Server.MapPath(folder_where_to_upload);
Server.MapPath("~/uploads/")`

Comment: no,it'll work on server too..but you need to give read/write permission of the folder from the server.

Comment: want to add this code also     if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(serverPath))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);